# Strange error logging in BBB

Tags: debian, tomcat

I have installed [BigBlueBotton](http://bigbluebutton.org) in Debian Stretch. However, when logging in with a "demo" user in the first page, I get back in Firefox a Tomcat/Java error complaining about a missing `bbb_api_conf.jsp` file that is bellow.

What to do?

```
HTTP Status 500 - /demo1.jsp (line: 38, column: 1) /bbb_api.jsp (line: 36, column: 1) File [bbb_api_conf.jsp] not found

type Exception report

message /demo1.jsp (line: 38, column: 1) /bbb_api.jsp (line: 36, column: 1) File [bbb_api_conf.jsp] not found

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /demo1.jsp (line: 38, column: 1) /bbb_api.jsp (line: 36, column: 1) File [bbb_api_conf.jsp] not found
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:291)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:97)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:348)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:381)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:484)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1800)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:142)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:127)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:197)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.8 (Debian) logs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error hints about a configuration file `bbb_api_conf.jsp`missing.

Checking out the [github](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/bigbluebutton-theme/blob/master/bbb_api_conf.jsp.dist) of the project, that file can be found as it is:

```
<%!
// This is the security salt that must match the value set in the BigBlueButton server
// You can get this by executing `bbb-conf --salt`
String salt = "";

// This is the URL for the BigBlueButton server
String BigBlueButtonURL = "";
%>
```

Following the suggestion of the file, we run:

```
$sudo bbb-conf --salt

   URL: http://bbb.internal/bigbluebutton/
  Salt: 5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5
```

So that file will be placed in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo/bbb_api_conf.jsp` as:

```
<%!
// This is the security salt that must match the value set in the BigBlueButton server
// You can get this by executing `bbb-conf --salt`
String salt = "5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5";

// This is the URL for the BigBlueButton server
String BigBlueButtonURL = "http://bbb.internal/bigbluebutton/";
%>
```

And there is also a need to do:

```
sudo chown tomcat8.tomcat8 /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/demo
```

After that, BBB opens correctely.

[image: bbb]